# Free text Search on Outlook/Exchange Global Address List (GAL)

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

When looking up contacts in the GAL, Outlook advanced search is not up to the task as I am not able to use wildcards.

Does anyone have an example of a PS script that allows me to do free text search on the GAL?

Either covering all the fields or, in alternative, on a single field that needs to be specified (like `Department` or `First name`, etc.)

Comment: Does this example more or less cover what you need? https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5igv98/using_powershell_to_access_the_global_address_list/

Comment: @james 
It helps, tks

Answer (score 0):

GAL Address book provider simply does not have that capability (even on the MAPI level). And looping through all items in GAL is a terrible idea as some GAL containers contain hundreds of thousands of entries.